# Replace a string with a variable containing newline characters

Tags: replace

I have a file that looks similar to this:

```
module.exports = {
    blank: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Magento/blank',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l',
            'css/email',
            'css/email-inline'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
    backend: {
        area: 'adminhtml',
        name: 'Magento/backend',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-old',
            'css/styles'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    }
};
```

I need to add another entry inside `module.exports`. I use vim inside a bash script in the following way:

```
THEME_CONFIG="\r    $LOWERCASE_THEME_TITLE: {\r
        area: 'frontend',\r
        name: '$ESCAPED_THEME_PATH',\r
        locale: 'en_US',\r
        files: [\r
            'css\/styles-m',\r
            'css\/styles-l'\r
        ],\r
        dsl: 'less'\r
    }\r
"

vim -c "%s/}\n/},$THEME_CONFIG\n/|wq" dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js
```

This works fine apart from the fact that I do not want to use `\r` as it seems to be breaking grunt. I would like to use `\n` instead, but if I replace `\r` in the code above with `\n` it does not work (`THEME_CONFIG` has no line breaks).

I have tried `\\n`, `$'\n'` but all I get is one line.

Comment: You should use the right tool for the right job and I think that here Vim isn't the right tool: in a non interactive bash shell you will most certainly have less trouble using `sed` (or maybe `awk`)

Comment: Confusingly, `\n` in a *search* pattern is a newline, but when used in a *replacement* pattern, it is a NULL character. Why this is the case I do not know, but the docs *do* say to use `\r` or equivalently `<CR>` / `^M`; the latter of which you can insert by pressing `Ctrl+V` `Enter`. Anyway, I agree with statox in that `sed` or `awk` would be a better choice for this, seeing as how you're only running a substitute command. You wouldn't have to deal with this quirk and could just use `\n` :)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12389839/1208424) has a great explanation for *why* `\n` is NULL in replacements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the `\r` characters in your string, but the fact that the string *also* contains literal newline characters, and Vim is including these in the replacement [as NUL characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12389839/328936) after the linebreaks. If you remove the latter from your bash script, then the replacement works correctly:

```
THEME_CONFIG="\r    $LOWERCASE_THEME_TITLE: {\r        area: 'frontend',\r        name: '$ESCAPED_THEME_PATH',\r        locale: 'en_US',\r [...]
```

If you (understandably) don't want to write your bash string on a single very long, line, there are [a number of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316107/bash-continuation-lines) you can split it up.

Note that you’re also including another NUL character in your substitution which needs to be changed to a `\r` linebreak:

```
vim -c "%s/}\n/},$THEME_CONFIG\n/|wq" ...
                              ^^
                              NUL character
```

Here's a complete solution, using line continuations to break up the string over several lines:

```
THEME_CONFIG="\r    $LOWERCASE_THEME_TITLE: {\r"\
"        area: 'frontend',\r"\
"        name: '$ESCAPED_THEME_PATH',\r"\
"        locale: 'en_US',\r"\
"        files: [\r"\
"            'css\/styles-m',\r"\
"            'css\/styles-l'\r"\
"        ],\r"\
"        dsl: 'less'\r"\
"    }\r"

vim -c "%s/}\n/},$THEME_CONFIG\r/|wq" themes.js
```

Comment: Actually I am. I had to go to the beginning of every line and hit backspace in order for grunt to stop complaining.

Comment: @KrzysztofWołowski Hmmm. What were you deleting from the file when you hit backspace? What's different between the incorrect file produced by Vim and the correct one produced by gawk?

Comment: @KrzysztofWołowski Ah, I see the problem, actually. Your string has newlines in it, as well as `\r` characters.

Comment: That may be the case but I remove `\r` from the string the output will be just one line.

Comment: @KrzysztofWołowski Don't remove the `\r` characters. Remove the newlines.

Comment: @KrzysztofWołowski See my update for a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the answers. `awk` (`gawk` in this particular case) is indeed the way to go. Though the solution has nothing to do with vim I paste it here just in case somebody stumbles upon this question.

```
THEME_CONFIG="    $LOWERCASE_THEME_TITLE: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: '$ESCAPED_THEME_PATH',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css\/styles-m',
            'css\/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    }
"

gawk -i inplace -v replacement="},\n$THEME_CONFIG" -v RS="" '{sub(/}\n/,replacement)}1' dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Two methods to append something in ex mode. You don't need to add `\r` in these methods.

But in this case, you should use `sed` or `awk`, feel free to ignore this answer.

**Append**

```
ex -sc +'if !search("}\\n") | q | endif' +'norm! A,' +"a|$THEME_CONFIG" +x theme.js
```

- +'if !search("}\n") | q | endif' exit if search failed. `:append` doesn't work well with `global` or `if`, you need to exit immediately if search failed.
- +'norm! A,' add `,` after `}`
- +"a|$THEME_CONFIG" append a block of text below current line. I didn't add the ending `.`, but it still works.
- +x save and exit

**Characterwise paste**

```
              v comma added here
THEME_CONFIG=",
    $LOWERCASE_THEME_TITLE: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: '$ESCAPED_THEME_PATH',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css\/styles-m',
            'css\/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    }"
     ^ no line break between } and "

ex -ns +"let @\"=\"$THEME_CONFIG\"" +'g/}\n/ norm! $p' +x  term.js
```

- `-ns` ignore recovery file, silent.
- `+"let@\"=\"$THEME_CONFIG\""` set default register to desired content. Because you want to add `,` directly after `}`, you must paste in characterwise mode, so you need to make sure `THEME_CONFIG` doesn't end in newline, otherwise your default register ended up in `linewise` mode. check `:h :let-@`.
- `+'g/}\n/ norm! $p'` search, go to line end, paste. check `:h :g`.